# Where is my ROM backup made in recovery mode saved?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, cyanogenmod

yesterday I had mz first experience with android phone - Samsung galaxy S4 mini.
I followed this instructions [Installing Cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_serranoltexx) and in recovery mode I made a backup of stock ROM (as is recommended).

I wonder where is this backup saved? I would like to transfer it to my PC.

In my PC I go to Internal/clockworkmod but there is only RECOVERY_VERSION File which has 42 bytes, so I guess it is not it :)

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

On your SD card (external, if available), a directory named `clockworkmod/backup` will be created, and on successful ROM backup inside that your nandroid backup lies. If the backup folder is not present inside the clockworkmod folder, it seems you have not taken backup successfully. In that case, try to take a complete backup using CWM properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you select 'Backup to sdcard1' location while made nandroid backup, check folder /storage/extSdCard/clockworkmod/backup/