# Why doesn't ClockWorkMod wipe of /data delete /data/media folder?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I think this might be a simple question but this been bugging me for long,

Why is that when i do a ClockWorkMod wipe of `/data`, the `/data/media` folder stays intact. @beeshyams [pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136902/why-doesnt-clockworkmod-wipe-of-data-delete-data-media-folder#comment173883_136902) that it is to avoid wiping out any clockworkmod backups. If that is the case, only `/data/media/clockworkmod/` folder will stay untouched if backups exists or not. But rather the whole `/data/media/` folder is kept safe from harms way. A better explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: To keep backups safe. See this http://android.stackexchange.com/a/132271/131553

Comment: How exactly is two different questions a "duplicate". its like asking what is 8/2  and someone says its a duplicate question of asking what is 2+2 cause they both answer 4.

Comment: @beeshyams edited the question appropriately addressing your opinion about it and why i find it not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Please note the following are *assumptions* based on my *Linux* knowledge. So I cannot 100% back them, especially cannot tell if any/all recoveries work this way.</sup>

First, some raw facts:

- as already pointed out, `/data/media` is a symlink to the SD card
- resulting of that, the data behind it *reside on a different partition*
- that other partition is usually *not* included with the wipe/[factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset), which normally covers only `/data` and `/cache`

So now to the wipe itself. "Emptying" the `/data` partition could be done in different ways:

- "formatting" the partition: wouldn't touch the data behind that symlink
- performing something like `rm -rf /data/*`: would remove the symlink, but leave the data behind it untouched
- walking the entire `/data/*` file by file, directory by directory, removing each entry (no idea why one would do that). In that case, unless the process *follows symlinks,* again only the symlink would be gone but the content behind it left untouched

So once more: As the data-in-question does not *physically* reside on the `/data` partition, it should even be *expected* to stay.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and would try to verify other comment and see if it matches. Would take time since CWM for my device is not original and modded and I still don't trust it enough to wipe and check

Comment: Make a complete backup first (Nandroid+SDCard-copy). But even when trying, that won't confirm the "why" but only the "if" ;)

Answer (score -2):

This thread [why doesn't format of /data in recovery blow away all your personal images, music, documents, etc?](http://androidforums.com/threads/international-gsm-why-doesnt-format-of-data-in-recovery-blow-away-all-your-personal-images-music-documents-etc.494216/) offers an answer

Quoting Scary Alien, who is a **moderator** on reddit forum (emphasis mine)

> ... when the `/data` partition is requested to be wiped with "`wipe_data`", the `erase_volume` (recovery.c) function is invoked. `erase_volume` invokes `format_volume` (roots.c). If `format_volume` determines if the volume in question is `/data` and `/data/media` is present and **symlinked to `/sdcard`**, then the `format_unknown_device` (extendedcommands.c) function is invoked. `format_unknown_device` will then recursively delete all files in `/data` -- **except for those in the `/data/media` structure**

In other words, as clarified in a trailing post

> Doing a data wipe in ClockworkMod will **skip** the `/data/media` folder (subdirectory)--i.e., where your **"`SD` card" lives**...

Comment: I'm curious here for 2 things: 1) @Firelord what does CyanogenMod code have to do with ClockWorkMod? 2) to beeshyams: if `/data/media` is a symlink *to another partition*, one could even "format" `/data` without the content there being lost. Initializing the device afterwards would restore the symlink – et voila, the content becomes visible again at this place. That would be my explanation – but as I've not checked into the code, I cannot back that claim and hence hesitated to answer.

Comment: @izzy: Possible .  I can't justify why not and as I said before can't read code either. However,  this is the only explanation I found

Comment: Didn't expect you to – just wanted to give an alternative explanation :) And as for CM vs CWM: it might well be recovery uses "ROM code" for that and Firelord wanted to check AOSP. Not having read the linked post I first thought someone had messed up the terms (missed the "W") – but scary alien built his argumentation on CM's recovery (obviously concluding other recoveries would behave the same). Hey, but even an `rm -rf /data/*` would just remove the symlink but leave the data behind it untouched :)

Comment: @izzy,  don't recall in the case of TWRP, where the backups are stored but for CWM it explains why backups are not deleted. That apart, as an ordinary user (= can't read code), explanation seems logical. Verification of ROM/CWM  is beyond the scope of this site, right?! . (One could seek validity of a recommended app (proposed in a solution) via code verification !!).

Comment: @izzy- And speculation on possibilities/ veracity does not serve any useful purpose, unless it is followed up and a conclusion  presented either way. When left hanging inconclusive, it may needlessly or unintentionally detract the OP (or anyone else reading it) from the solution presented

Comment: Agreed on speculations *if not based on facts* (you could count my answer as "speculation" in a way – but it's based on facts which are convincing even me (or I hadn't posted it). And it even matches your quote: I bet if you'd e.g. `ln -s /system/app /data/sysapp`, the wipe of `/data` wouldn't even *try* touching `/system/app` but rather count `/data/sysapp` as what it is: a symlink to be removed but not followed. So I'm pretty sure that's what's standing behind it. // And ack #2: I'd also like to know the reason of that downvote.

Comment: @izzy- let me clarify. I was not meaning you, at all. As a matter of fact, I did not even see your answer,till much later (owing to the fact that I mostly work out of mobile and miss the literal "big picture" on what is added in other answers). I squarely and even now consider Firelord"s comments as speculations not acted upon thus adding no value and maybe detracting value from the answer

Comment: It's ok if someone wishes to downvote but was curious as to the reason. Incidentally the comment asking " why downvote" seems to be deleted (maybe by me when we were chatting on wee hours but I don't recollect doing so)